# PHP search function generating server timeout

Tags: php, search

I have a PHP search function that is triggered when an html form is submitted. I've been noticing that when I enter a string longer than 4-5 characters, the search timesout. There are over 2000 records in the database, could that be why it's not able to return search results?

```
$country=$HTTP_POST_VARS['country'];
$catagory=$HTTP_POST_VARS['catagory'];
$pricemin=$HTTP_POST_VARS['pricemin'];
$pricemax=$HTTP_POST_VARS['pricemax'];
$sort=$HTTP_POST_VARS['sort'];
$searchword=$HTTP_POST_VARS['searchword'];

$search = '?'.'catagory='.$catagory.'&country='.$country;

if ( $pricemax <> '' )
    $search = $search.'&pricemax='.$pricemax;
else
    $search = $search.'&pricemin=0';
if ( $pricemax <> '' )
    $search = $search.'&pricemax='.$pricemax;
if ( $sort <> '' )
    $search = $search.'&sort='.$sort;
if ( $searchword <> '' )
    {
    $wordformated = str_replace(" ", ",", $searchword);
    $search = $search.'&searchword='.$wordformated;
    }

header("Location: results.php".$search);
```

Comment: Here is the form tag that's calling the php file: <form action="search.php" method="POST">

Comment: Is this new code or old code? I haven't seen `HTTP_POST_VARS` in I don't know how long! Anyway, put a `die('here');` right before the `header` statement. Do all your queries happen really fast then? If so, the problem is on results.php.

Comment: This is not search script. This code generates url to redirect. `Results.php` executes search.

Comment: Yes this is old code! It's so so old, thanks for the help! They rebooted the (ancient) server that is running some version of PHP 4 and that solved it.